# Why are the contents of my KendoUI ListView disappear when I click on them?

Tags: listview, asp.net-mvc-4, controls, kendo-ui

I've followed the editing example from [this](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/listview/editing.html) tutorial, and managed to achieve a similar behavior for my web page, but there's a problem which I don't understand why it happens. Every time I click on the Edit button or Delete button, the element on the List View associated to those buttons disappears from the list. This is my javascript function for displaying the List View:

```
function swapDiv(e) {
    selection = e.value;
    var url = '';
    switch (selection) { //check from which endpoint I will be loading the contents for the list view
        case 'Usuarios':
            url = "http://127.0.0.1:81/SismosService.svc/usuario/index";
            template = '#usuariosTemplate';
            break;
        case 'Regiones':
            url = "http://127.0.0.1:81/SismosService.svc/region/index";
            template = '#regionesTemplate';
            break;
        case 'Clusters':
            url = "http://127.0.0.1:81/SismosService.svc/cluster/index";
            template = '#clustersTemplate';
            break;
        case 'Dispositivos':
            url = "http://127.0.0.1:81/SismosService.svc/dispositivo/index";
            template = '#dispositivosTemplate';
            break;
        case 'Eventos':
            url = "http://127.0.0.1:81/SismosService.svc/evento/index";
            template = '#eventosTemplate';
            break;
    }
    $.ajax({ //make the ajax call to load the contents for the list view
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            var src = null;
            if (template == '#eventosTemplate')
            {
                src = getEventosArray(data); //the controls displayed for this kind of data are different from the rest
            }
            else
            {
                src = data.Response; 
            }
            var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: src
            });
            $('#listView').kendoListView({ //create the kendo ui list view
                dataSource: ds,
                template: kendo.template($(template).html())
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
    //animate the div where the list view and other controls are displayed
    $('#selectionBar').animate({
        left : '189'
    }, 500);
    $('#dataBar').animate({
        left: '0'
    }, 500);
    $('#myMap').animate({
        left : '370'
    }, 500);
}
```

The templates I defined for the List View are in [this](http://pastebin.com/QafEmUgV) link. Finally this is my View:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link href="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.common.min.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.default.min.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.web.min.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3"></script>
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/index/templateLoader.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/index/main.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<%-- here goes my templates but for space reasons and to provide a more clean reading I put the templates separately --%>


</head>
<body onload="GetMap();">
    <div id="canvasDiv" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: transparent; left: 10px; ">
        <div id="mainDiv" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: transparent; left: 10px; ">
            <div id="leftBar" style="border: thin solid #666666; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0; width: 180px; height: 100%; background-color: white; left: 10px; overflow:auto; z-index:20">
                <button id="btnUsuarios" value="Usuarios" style="position: absolute;left: 10px; right: 10px; top: 10px; width: auto; height: 50px" class="k-button" onclick="swapDiv(this)">Usuarios</button><br />
                <button id="btnRegiones" value="Regiones" style="position: absolute;left: 10px; right: 10px; top: 70px; width: auto; height: 50px" class="k-button" onclick="swapDiv(this)">Regiones</button><br />
                <button id="btnClusters" value="Clusters" style="position: absolute;left: 10px; right: 10px; top: 130px; width: auto; height: 50px" class="k-button" onclick="swapDiv(this)">Clusters</button><br />
                <button id="btnDispositivos" value="Dispositivos" style="position: absolute;left: 10px; right: 10px; top: 190px; width: auto; height: 50px" class="k-button" onclick="swapDiv(this)">Dispositivos</button><br />
                <button id="btnEventos" value="Eventos" style="position: absolute;left: 10px; right: 10px; top: 250px; width: auto; height: 50px" class="k-button" onclick="swapDiv(this)">Eventos</button><br />
            </div>
            <div id="selectionBar" style="border: thin solid #666666; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0; width: 180px; height: 100%; background-color: white; left: 10px; overflow:auto; z-index:9">
                <div class="k-toolbar k-grid-toolbar">
                    <button class="k-button k-button-icontext k-add-button" onclick="swapToNewData(this)"><span class="k-icon k-add"></span>Agregar</button>
                </div>
                <div id="listView" style="background-color: transparent; position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 0px; right: 0px; width:auto; height:auto" ></div>
            </div>
            <div id="dataBar" style="border: thin solid #666666; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0; width: 180px; height: 100%; background-color: white; left: 10px; overflow:auto; z-index:8">
                <div id="dataView" style="background-color: transparent; position: absolute; top: 40px; bottom:0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; width:auto; height:auto" ></div>
            </div>
            <div id='myMap' style="border: thin solid black; position: absolute; display: block; min-height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 189px; width: 88%; "></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What's the reason for the contents of my List View to disappear? is it a behavior embedded in the Kendo UI List View control? How can I avoid this behavior?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few circumstances that make the elements disappear. Typical are:

- There is no `update` mode in the DataSource definition.
- There is no `id` (or even `model`) in the `DataSource` definition.

From your DataSource I see that there is no `model` definition.

**EDIT**

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/NUrmV/) I have defined a Grid with a model but I have commented the `id` definition in the model. If you click on `edit` button and then `cancel`, you will see the row disappear.

Commented `id` definition:

```
schema   : {
    model: {
        // id    : "symbol",
        fields: {
            symbol: { type: "string" },
            price : { type: "number" },
            shares: { type: "number" },
            total : { type: "number" }
        }
    }
},
```

Now, remove the comment in the `id` definition and repeat the test, you will see that now the row is not removed from the grid.

```
schema   : {
    model: {
        id    : "symbol",
        fields: {
            symbol: { type: "string" },
            price : { type: "number" },
            shares: { type: "number" },
            total : { type: "number" }
        }
    }
},
```

**EDIT**:

Seems that you are missing the edition template in your definition. For `usuariosTemplate` it should be something like:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="usuariosTemplateEdit">
    <div class="product-view">
        <dl>
            <dt>Usuario</dt>
            <dd>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value:Nombre" name="Nombre" required="required"/>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: ApellidoP" name="ApellidoP" required="required" />
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: ApellidoM" name="ApellidoM" required="required" />
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <div class="edit-buttons">
            <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-update-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-update"></span>Save</a>
            <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-cancel-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-cancel"></span>Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

and you should also change your code for adding the extra option in the listView initialization:

Example of the listView for usuarios (hardcode version).

```
$('#listView').kendoListView({
    dataSource  : ds,
    template    : kendo.template($('#usuariosTemplate').html()),
    editTemplate: kendo.template($('#usuariosTemplateEdit').html())
});
```

Comment: so I should define a schema? since I just wanted to display the info on a List View I thought it wasn't necessary, the behavior for the edit and delete buttons I was redirecting them to another functions to display the data, that's because the amount of info is large and displaying all of the info in a List View didn't look like a good idea to me. The schema I have to define must be based on the info I want to display? or do I have to put all of the fields that represent the data I'm receiving?

Comment: @UrielArvizu, please read the edited answer and play with example to see what I mean.

Comment: ok, I edited the function to look like [this](http://pastebin.com/csCp1xD8) but it keeps disappearing, I'm only displaying the Nombre, ApellidoP and ApellidoM properties, I also tried putting all of the properties an Usuario object has, but it still didn't stop the elements from disappearing, what am I missing?

Comment: Oops! seems that you are not defining the template for editing (needs to be defined). See my last **edit** to the answer.

Comment: but I don't want to edit, I just want to display the info in a List View, I used the editing example from that page just to display the info. Does a List View forcefully needs an editTemplate?

Comment: I think that I'm getting lost! Of course they don't have to be editable but then why did you define an edit and remove button? Did you try removing them? That should be enough!

Comment: oh that's because I want to edit the info but on a different div, that's because there's entities with many fields, and displaying all of that info in a List View would look bad, I put those buttons to  populate another div with the corresponding fields. Is there's a way to keep the buttons without adding an EditTemplate?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23604/discussion-between-onabai-and-uriel-arvizu)